# If $q$ is a final surjection(i.e. a quotient map) , then $q^{-1}[cl(B)] = cl (q^{-1}[B])$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve a problem on a certain class of topological spaces. Proving the following will solve my dilemma.

Let $q: (X,\mathcal{T}) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{S})$ be a quotient map. Is it true that $q^{-1}[cl(B)] = cl(q^{-1}[B])$ for all subsets $B$ of $Y$.
Since $q$ is a quotient map, $q$ is surjective and the topology $\mathcal{S}$ on $Y$ is given by $\{U \subset Y\ |\ q^{-1}[U] \in \mathcal{T}\}$. In particular a subset $B$ of $Y$ is closed iff $q^{-1}[B]$  is closed in $(X,\mathcal{T}).$
Now, if $B \subset Y$, then $B \subset cl(B)$ so that $q^{-1}[B] \subset q^{-1}[cl(B)]$ and since $q^{-1}[cl(B)]$ is closed in $X$, it easily follows that $cl(q^{-1}[B]) \subset q^{-1}[cl[B]]$. I am struggling with the reverse inclusion, I know that if $cl(q^{-1}[B]) =q^{-1}[B']$ for some subset $B'$ of $Y$. Then $B'$ must be closed and clearly $B \subset B' \subset cl(B)$ so that  $B' = cl(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q:I\to S^1$ be the quotient map $t \mapsto (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$. If $B=\{(x,y)\in S^1 \mid y>0\}$, then $q^{-1}\left(\overline B\right)$ contains $1$ while $\overline{q^{-1}(B)}$ does not.

Actually, $q^{-1}\left(\overline B\right) \subseteq \overline{q^{-1}(B)}$ is equivalent to $q$ being an open map, and the quotient map I used in my example is not open.

The reverse inclusion is equivalent to $q$ being a continuous map.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem using a little extra hypothesis on the space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ which is part of the problem. I thought I might be able to show it more generally, but it turns out, it's not possible. For interest sake, I'll include the condition: Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a space that satisfies the following condition: $\forall x \in X\forall A \subset X : x \in clA \Leftrightarrow \exists a \in A : x \in cl\{a\}.$ Then this result does hold.

Comment: I seems worth adding that $I=[0,1]$ and $S^{1}=\{(x,y)\,|\,x,y \in \mathbb{R},x^2+y^2=1\}$.